# React Native, a path for sub sub folder from a file in sub folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have root has App.ja which calls Discovery.js screen from screens folder, and Discovery.js has to get image from asset/gallery/image/my.png , i want to know how to write the path the my.png file?
I tried this (from inside Discover.js):

```
 let imagePath = require('./././asset/gallery/image/my.png');


project (root)
|
+—screen
|    |
|    +—Discover.js
|
+—asset
|    |
|    +—gallery
|          |
|          +—image
|              |
|              +—my.png
```

I got this error:

Unable to resolve module `./././asset/gallery/image/` from `screens/Discover.js`:

None of these files exist:

- screens/asset/gallery/image(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- screens/asset/gallery/image/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

RCTFatal
__28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
**CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE**
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start

Answer (score 1):

Change your path to `../../asset/gallery/image/my.png` 
`..` goes back a directory. Not `.`.

Comment: Can you give any other information? Are you getting an error? What else have you tried?

Comment: @HowardJohn you want to use `require('../asset/gallery/image/my.png')` in your case